# How can I save a file using Orbeon XForms locally on the disk and make it available for download?

Tags: file-upload, orbeon, xforms

I'm struggling a bit with the syntax of Orbeon/XForms. I'm trying to create a form from which you can upload a file and save it locally on the disk then make it available for download. Or better, display the contents of a directory from the disk and make the files downloadable.

The idea is to upload xml files and then a process in the background converts them to different formats and make those available for download.

Until now, I have this:

```
<xf:upload ref=".">
  <xf:filename>file:////home/me/data-in/*.xml</xf:filename>
  <xf:mediatype>text/xml</xf:mediatype>
</xf:upload>
<br/>
<xf:output ref=".">
   <xf:label>File: </xf:label>
 </xf:output>
```

The problem is that the file is not stored where I would have wanted to be saved (file:////home/me/data-in/*.xml) but instead in /home/me/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/temp and with a different name.

Can anyone give me some ideas, examples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the "disk" you referring to is the one the server, not the one on the user's side.

It's not possible to choose the location: all uploaded files are *temporary* files. Generally, the XForms engine doesn't have direct access to the filesystem.

This said, if you just want to do an upload/download, try the File Attachment control, for example [here](http://demo.orbeon.com/orbeon/fr/orbeon/controls/new).

If you want to use it "by hand":

```
<fr:attachment ref="my-data" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner">
    <xf:label>Attached file</xf:label>
     <!-- Optional -->
    <xf:filename ref="@filename"/>
    <xf:mediatype ref="@mediatype"/>
    <xxf:size ref="@size"/>
</fr:attachment>
```

This control provides you with a built-in Download link.